# Get specific chars from the string - PHP

Tags: php

I am looking at several functions that either get string between 2 strings or specific chars but I have a dilemma here so please help me out.

The string is

```
You are currently using plugin version 8.0.3 Stable - 11-08-2013
```

since there are several plugins that can be used the version and date might change. 
What I need is only 8.0.3 to be returned from this string but I will never know if it is 8.0.2 or 8.0.25. or 10.5.33 for that matter.

So instead of guessing cases , order of words , exploding the string , spaces or looking before version and after Stable

what I would rather have is: 
**get the numbers before the first dot and after last and return string with the dots.**

**NOTE: I do not want to search between version and Stable , already have that , their order might be reversed, thus I asked for a match with DOTS**
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really be using a regex here

```
$str = 'You are currently using plugin version 8.0.3 Stable - 11-08-2013';
preg_match('/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)/',$str, $match);
```

`$match[1]` will contain `8.0.3`, and will still work for `10.25.24` or `32154.0.165741354`.

Comment: Seems like , I thought strrpos is faster but I have 2 strrpos and substr wich than compared to speed comes back equalish

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$str = 'You are currently using plugin version 8.0.3 Stable - 11-08-2013';

$start = strpos($str, '.')-1;
$end = strrpos($str, '.')+2;
$version = substr($str, $start, $end - $start);
```

Comment: @Benn Just a quick comment, for posterity's sake, that this will fail if the first or last number has multiple digits

Comment: You can seek from start to space, and then cut the string

Comment: Yes yes , just figured ,   it picks up max of 1 last number , we need up to 2  eg:  if 8.0.15  it shows 8.0.1,  but if changed to +3 instaed of 2 it would work, kinda iffy

Comment: @Benn you'd need to to go left from the first dot until the first non-digit and right from the last dot until the first non-digit.

Comment: @T0xicCode any example of the last post by using anything else but preg_match ?

Comment: @Benn You'd have to treat the string as an array, and move `$start` left (smaller) as long as `ctype_digit($str[$start])` returns true (and similarly, but going right for `$end`).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match the content you need.

```
$str = 'You are currently using plugin version 8.0.3 Stable - 11-08-2013';
preg_match('/version (.*?) Stable/',$str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Same thing as the other, I do not want to search between stable and version , maybe I was not specific enough

Comment: @Benn In this case, `$match[1]` will contain `8.0.3`. What is the output you want, using the given string?

Comment: I know that but I started my post and explained that I do not want the match between 2 words ,reason being is that in some plugin they can be reversed or not present , I need to look for those dots

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to get the version number from that string:

```
$str = 'You are currently using plugin version 8.0.3 Stable - 11-08-2013';
preg_match('/[0-9\.]+/',$str, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

the $match[1] is 8.0.3

Comment: This question is relate to PHP not javascript.

Comment: @RahilWazir , sorry i didn't notice that , i edited it pls remove the vote down :(

Answer (score -1):

```
function findit( $mytext , $starttag , $endtag ) 
          {

              $posLeft = stripos( $mytext , $starttag )+strlen( $starttag );
              $posRight = stripos( $mytext , $endtag , $posLeft+1);
              return substr( $mytext , $posLeft , $posRight-$posLeft );

          }
```

first parameter is the text var , second is the start text , third is for end text

- get text between $starttag and $endtag from $mytext

Comment: I think I was specific as to what I need. I dont want to search between words